# error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oe51.jpg)When I tried to build my project this pops out of the error list: "error: option --boot-class-path not allowed with target 11"

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: please add the parts of code that returns error to your question.

Comment: @parisssss I already edited and added a picture. I'm actually not really sure if it's what you're asking for. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: same issue when building an ant project in netbeans